# How to set focus of a pyqt5 pushbutton in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pynput

I'm creating a virtual keyboard using pyqt5 python3 to type on other applications. And I'm using .ui file as GUI. For writing /typing I'm using pynput keyboard. So I want to type the letters by clicking on the pushbuttons. But whenever I click on the key buttons it takes the focus and doesn't write. So what is the solution to it? my code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

class Ui_self(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("self")
        self.resize(150, 200)
        self.secret_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.secret_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 100, 105))
        self.secret_button.setText("# tag")
        # self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.ToolTip)       <---
        # self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) <----
        # self.secret_button.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus) <----
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_self()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The problem is that clicking on a button results in the window getting focused, so your problem is not to set focus, but the exact opposite. Try by adding `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.ToolTip)` (but that's not guaranteed to work in the same way on all platforms).

Comment: adding self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.ToolTip) dose'nt work!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of what you've tried so far. Note: it should be **both** minimal *and* reproducible.

Comment: I've updated my question with code please check it out.

Comment: did you try to set the tooltip flag **only**? Because if you did try to set both ToolTip *and* WindowStaysOnTopHint, it won't work: the second flag will clear the first.

Comment: Yes, I have tried! But that did not work

Comment: As said, that's not guaranteed to work on any platform. I can correctly keep focus on the current object on the screen after clicking on your UI, as long as only the ToolTip flag is set (I don't even need to set the focus policy), but that's on Linux running fluxbox (there could be other window managers that behave differently). I cannot give you more hints about this, as it probably needs some deeper platform API management; but I can suggest you to specify on what OS (and version) you're going to run this, maybe somebody else could be able to help you.